# How can I export my history in Google Translation?

Tags: google-translate

I want to print those words or statements that I've used Google translate on. Is there any way to export them to spreadsheet, say Google Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google translate doesn't keep a history of things you've translated. Since this is the case there isn't no way to export your previous translation history.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to  export it with google chrome? (with history of Chrome?)

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi perhaps, I wouldn't know. but that's another question and not on topic for [webapps.se]

Comment: oh. yes. thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

Once you translate a word or group of words click the star (on the left or right side) to save it, then you can export the word/words that you saved as Excel sheet. Click on the saved button; it is a star beneath the translation box to see all the words that you saved. You can print them out or export them as Excel sheet, that will be a little report on the right side of the your saved words box). I used to save every word I translated and print them later as group.

[image]